# Некорректная работа input

Tags: javascript, html

Нашёл в интернете кусочек кода, который из `input type="range"` выводит цифровое значение в `input type="text"`. Если двигать ползунок - меняется значение в `input type="text"`, если менять значение в `input type="text"`, то ползунок двигается.  Для `input text` так-же есть 2 кнопки, + и -, которые по единице меняют значение в `input`-е. Всё условно работает, только одна загвоздка. При смене числа, ползунок в `input type="range"` не двигается, хоть и значение в `input type="text"` меняется кнопками.

В чём проблема?

```js
function fun1() {
  var rng = document.getElementById("r1"); //rng - это ползунок
  var i1 = document.getElementById("i1"); // i1 - input
  i1.value = rng.value;
}

function fun2() {
  var rng = document.getElementById("r1"); //rng - это ползунок
  var i1 = document.getElementById("i1"); // i1 - input
  rng.value = i1.value;
}
const counter = function() {
  const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".counter-button");

  btns.forEach((btn) => {
    btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
      const direction = this.dataset.direction;
      const inp = this.parentElement.querySelector(".counter-input");
      const currentValue = +inp.value;
      let newValue;

      if (direction === "plus") {
        newValue = currentValue + 1;
      } else {
        newValue = currentValue - 1 > 0 ? currentValue - 1 : 0;
      }

      inp.value = newValue;
    });
  });
};
counter();
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <div class="ip-range d-flex">
    <input type="range" id="r1" value="5" max="20" oninput="fun1()" />
    <div style="display: flex; width: auto">
      <div class="range-button">
        <button class="counter-button" data-direction="minus">
                            - 
        </button>
        <input class="counter-input" type="text" oninput="fun2()" id="i1" />
        <button class="counter-button" data-direction="plus">
                             +
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `fun2()` вызывается только если ввести число в `input type="text"` вручную. При смене числа вводом с клавиатуры все сработает. А почему не использовать `input type="number"`?

Answer (score 2):

Добавил в функцию `counter()` искусственный вызов ONINPUT, а в тег самого `input type="text"` attribute `value="5"`.

```js
function fun1() {
  var rng = document.getElementById("r1"); //rng - это ползунок
  var i1 = document.getElementById("i1"); // i1 - input
  i1.value = rng.value;
}

function fun2() {
  var rng = document.getElementById("r1"); //rng - это ползунок
  var i1 = document.getElementById("i1"); // i1 - input
  rng.value = i1.value;
}
const counter = function() {
  const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".counter-button");

  btns.forEach((btn) => {
    btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
      const direction = this.dataset.direction;
      const inp = this.parentElement.querySelector(".counter-input");
      const currentValue = +inp.value;
      let newValue;

      if (direction === "plus") {
        newValue = currentValue + 1;
      } else {
        newValue = currentValue - 1 > 0 ? currentValue - 1 : 0;
      }

      inp.value = newValue;
      inp.dispatchEvent(new Event('input')); // ДОБАВИЛ СЮДА ВЫЗОВ ONINPUT
    });
  });
};
counter();
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <div class="ip-range d-flex">
    <input type="range" id="r1" value="5" max="20" oninput="fun1()" />
    <div style="display: flex; width: auto">
      <div class="range-button">
        <button class="counter-button" data-direction="minus">
                            - 
        </button>
        <input class="counter-input" type="text" value="5" oninput="fun2()" id="i1" />
        <button class="counter-button" data-direction="plus">
                             +
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

А можно просто поменять на `input type="number"` и никаких функций `counter` и кнопок не надо.

```js
function fun1() {
  var rng = document.getElementById("r1"); //rng - это ползунок
  var i1 = document.getElementById("i1"); // i1 - input
  i1.value = rng.value;
}

function fun2() {
  var rng = document.getElementById("r1"); //rng - это ползунок
  var i1 = document.getElementById("i1"); // i1 - input
  rng.value = i1.value;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <div class="ip-range d-flex">
<input type="range" id="r1" value="5" max="20" oninput="fun1()" />
<div style="display: flex; width: auto">
  <div class="range-button">
    <input class="counter-input" type="number" value="5" step="1" oninput="fun2()" id="i1" />

  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Можно обойтись вообще одними короткими инструкциями в самих инпутах:

```html
<input type="range" style="display: block" id="r1" value="5" max="20" oninput="document.getElementById('i1').value = this.value" />
<input class="counter-input" type="number" min="0" max="20" value="5" oninput="document.getElementById('r1').value = this.value" step="1" id="i1" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Если долго не копаться, то и вот так сойдет. Выбрать по селектору range и давать ему значения при нажатии на кнопки

```js
function fun1() {
  var rng = document.getElementById("r1"); //rng - это ползунок
  var i1 = document.getElementById("i1"); // i1 - input
  i1.value = rng.value;
}

function fun2() {
  var rng = document.getElementById("r1"); //rng - это ползунок
  var i1 = document.getElementById("i1"); // i1 - input
  rng.value = i1.value;
}
const counter = function() {
  const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".counter-button");

  btns.forEach((btn) => {
    btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
      const direction = this.dataset.direction;
      const inp = this.parentElement.querySelector(".counter-input");
      const currentValue = +inp.value;
      const sl = document.querySelector("#r1");
      let newValue;

      if (direction === "plus") {
        newValue = currentValue + 1;
        sl.value = newValue;
      } else {
        newValue = currentValue - 1 > 0 ? currentValue - 1 : 0;
        sl.value = newValue
      }

      inp.value = newValue;
    });
  });
};
counter();
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <div class="ip-range d-flex">
    <input type="range" id="r1" value="5" max="20" oninput="fun1()" />
    <div style="display: flex; width: auto">
      <div class="range-button">
        <button class="counter-button" data-direction="minus">
                            - 
        </button>
        <input class="counter-input" type="text" oninput="fun2()" id="i1" />
        <button class="counter-button" data-direction="plus">
                             +
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```